# Elisp: what's the complete regex for symbol name?

Tags: emacs, elisp

I've encountered cases when `prin1-to-string` and `read` aren't
reverse of each other for symbols, e.g.:

```lisp
(prin1-to-string (read "foo?"))
;; "foo\\?"
(prin1-to-string (read "foo."))
;; "foo\\."
```

I'd like to know about all possible cases for which this happens.
I'm especially interested in a method to distinguish between different source
codes that produce the same code, e.g.:

```lisp
(prin1-to-string (read "foo."))
;; "foo\\."
(prin1-to-string (read "foo\\."))
;; "foo\\."
```

I'm thinking of doing a regex replace of the iffy symbols like `foo.bar` into
e.g. `'(raw "foo.bar")` before passing it to `read`. But I'd need to know
the complete regex for these iffy symbols.

I've had a look in the info pages, but haven't found a precise syntax for symbol
yet.

Comment: `foo.` and `foo\.` are the **same** symbol.  Why do you need to tell them apart?

Comment: They're same in code, but not in source code. I'm writing code that modifies source code, that's why I want to differentiate `foo.` and `foo\.`.

Comment: Replacing one with the other doesn't change the meaning of the source code, though, so you could treat them as identical with regards to source code as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I couldn't find it in the documentation, but according to the [source code](https://github.com/mirrors/emacs/blob/50e0de73b966005804f9349bf37d7c6478be3cc2/src/print.c#L1575-L1580), it seems like the following characters are quoted when a symbol is being printed:

- `"`
- `\`
- `'`
- `;`
- `#`
- `(`
- `)`
- `,`
- `.`
- `` ` ``
- `[`
- `]`
- `?`
- all control characters (`<= 040`)

Also, if the symbol name begins with a digit, and ends with a digit, and contains nothing but digits and `e`, then the first character is escaped:

```
ELISP> (prin1-to-string (make-symbol "2e5"))
"\\2e5"
```

Of course, the ones you are interested in are only the ones that would be *read* as part of the symbol.  It seems like `?` and `.` are indeed the only ones that can be read when unescaped.

Comment: Thanks. Although it would be great to have a formal specification in the manual.

Answer (score 3):

Indeed, prin1-to-string and read are supposed to be inverses of each other, but only in one direction: `(read-from-string (print1-to-string X)) ~ X`. and of course, only for objects which are printable, an you may need to set `print-circle` and a few other such vars (`print-depth`, ..) to make sure that it holds.